# Setting BrowserWindow frame: false disables click events

Tags: electron

I wrote an electron app that has a html table with click events on the first column. The click events fire as long as BrowserWindow frame: true if I change it to false the click events on the table stop working. I also have a button on the same page that is not affected by changing the frame property. Anyone know why this happens or a work around?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Please add a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: In addition to what @snwflk said, you could also write your example in Electron fiddle https://electronjs.org/fiddle so it's easier for other Electron users to quickly get to the bottom of your problem

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the click events was that I made the window that the table is located in a draggable region and forgot that doing so makes items not clickable. So in my css for the table I added this line "-webkit-app-region: no-drag" which solved the problem.

Comment: Made my day bro! Solved the problem.